# how to convert the following html into jade

Tags: html, pug

The following is the code i want to convert to jade from html.

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test it here: http://jade-lang.com/demo/

```
video(width="320", height="240", controls)
  source(src="movie.mp4", type="video/mp4")
  source(src="movie.ogg", type="video/ogg")
  |Your browser does not support the video tag.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://html2jade.org/ to convert in both directions.

(HTML2Jade referenced by @Sushrut is a dead link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to convert vice-verse : [HTML2Jade](http://html2jade.com/)